# Error accessing object property in module

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class, es6-modules

I'm currently running some tests with JavaScript modules, unfortunately there is an Uncaught TypeError error when trying to set the property, setOption, of the mychart object. This is passed as a parameter to a class that is in another module. The current code looks like this:

App.js

```
import {   echart,   theme,   option } from './module-chart';

import {   ChartController } from './module-chart-controller';

let mychart = echart.init(document.getElementById('main'), theme); 
mychart.setOption(option);

let chartController = new ChartController(mychart); 
chartController.animateChart();
```

module-chart-controller.js

```
class ChartController{

  constructor(chart){
    this.mychart = chart;
  }

  animateChart() {
    let intervalo = setInterval(function() {
      concentrationOfAandB = getObjectConcentrationOfAandB();
      dataA.push(concentrationOfAandB.concentrationOfA);
      dataB.push(concentrationOfAandB.concentrationOfB);
      this.mychart.setOption({
        series: [{
            data: dataA,
            animationDuration: 1000
          },
          {
            data: dataB,
            animationDuration: 1000
          }
        ]
      });
    }, 1900);
    setTimeout(function() {
      clearInterval(intervalo);
    }, 40000);
  }
}
export {ChartController};
```

When I pass the module-chart-controller.js code in the App.js file, no error occurs.

The following error message is displayed on the console: **Uncaught TypeError: Can not read property 'setOption' of undefined.** Accusing error in module-chart-controller.js file

Thank you in advance for your attention!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `bind` the method where you are requesting properties assigned to `this`, so the method has access to them. And the same you need to do the `setInterval` function, it needs access to `this`, so you need to `bind` it too.

```
constructor(chart){
    this.mychart = chart;
    this.animateChart = this.animateChart.bind(this);
}

animateChart() {
    let intervalo = setInterval(function() {
       concentrationOfAandB = getObjectConcentrationOfAandB();
       dataA.push(concentrationOfAandB.concentrationOfA);
       dataB.push(concentrationOfAandB.concentrationOfB);
       this.mychart.setOption({
           series: [{
               data: dataA,
               animationDuration: 1000
           },
           {
               data: dataB,
               animationDuration: 1000
           }]
       });
    }.bind(this), 1900);

    setTimeout(function() {
        clearInterval(intervalo);
    }, 40000);
}
```

Comment: You need to `bind` the `setInterval` function too. I updated my answer.

Comment: Tks for the solution! It helped a lot